# Given number n. Print numbers from 2 to n, next to each number write its divisors (except for the number itself)

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Given number n. Print numbers from 2 to n, next to each number write its divisors (except for the number itself).

For example for n = 6(correct output):

> 2 - 1
>
> 3 - 1
>
> 4 - 1, 2
>
> 5 - 1
>
> 6 - 1, 2, 3

**I solved the problem itself, or rather I could find the divisors for each number, but the difficulty comes out with the conclusion. Here is my code:**

```
n = int(input("Введите число: "))
for i in range(2,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j ==0:
            print(f'{i} - {j}')
```

**My output:**

> 2 - 1
>
> 3 - 1
>
> 4 - 1
>
> 4 - 2
>
> 5 - 1
>
> 6 - 1
>
> 6 - 2
>
> 6 - 3

*I don't know how to fix this. Can you, please, suggest with ignorance of what topic my error with the output is connected and how can I solve it?*

Answer (score 0):

By default `print()` puts a newline at the end. So you have to ignore this newline in your case.

```
n = int(input("Введите число: "))
for i in range(2,n+1):
    print(f'{i} -', end = '')
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j ==0:
            print(f' {j}', end = '')
    print()
```

Comment: It is also necessary that there are commas between the numbers. I didn't figure it out either

Comment: Well, I can't do everything for you. You have to try that yourself. It should be easy. @Ben

Comment: Where can I read about the question that I asked?

Comment: Which question? @Ben

Comment: How to make it so that there are also commas between the numbers. If this seems simple enough to you, then for me this is an incomprehensible topic.

Comment: @Ben So, you know how to insert dashes between numbers but commas are incomprehensible? That's bizarre.

Comment: I know how to put those dumb commas. The problem is that they appear at the end of each line and I cannot remove them, so that they also remain in the middle. Tried to use but rstrip() doesn't work